# How do I format a string to UUID in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little VBA project, but I'm having an issue.

I need to take a 32-character hexadecimal string and turn it into a UUID.

```
Input: b10a8db164e0754105b7a99be72e3fe5
Output: b10a8db1-64e0-7541-05b7-a99be72e3fe5
```

I have no idea where to start with this, but I'm thinking I would need to split the string after so many characters and then re-combine it. Any pointers or methods to do this efficiently?

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mid.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Left`, `Right` and `Mid` to make this into the format you want.

```
Function makeUuid(asString As String) As String
    Dim asUuidFormat As String
    If Len(asString) <> 32 Then
        makeUuid = asString
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim firstPart As String, secondPart As String, thirdPart As String, fourthPart As String, fifthPart As String
    firstPart = Left(asString, 8)
    secondPart = Mid(asString, 9, 4)
    thirdPart = Mid(asString, 13, 4)
    fourthPart = Mid(asString, 17, 4)
    fifthPart = Right(asString, 12)
    makeUuid = firstPart & "-" & secondPart & "-" & thirdPart & "-" & fourthPart & "-" & fifthPart
End Function
```

Which you can use in a worksheet as `=makeUuid(A4)' (or whatever cell)

[image]

If you pass in something other than a 32 length character string it does no formatting and just returns the original string.

Comment: Works awesome, thanks. I was actually playing with MID() when you posted this, so your comment really helped. Take +25 rep.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1** in another cell:

```
=MID(A1,1,8) & "-" & MID(A1,9,4) & "-" & MID(A1,13,4) & "-" & MID(A1,17,4) & "-" & MID(A1,21,9999)
```